# Sort Ordering In Selective Fetching - Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm looking to fetch some objects stored in my core data model with an NSPredicate and a NSSortDescriptor:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"myObjectList.objectID like %@", objectID];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor 
                          sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortKey" ascending:NO];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [MyObject fetchRequest];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
[fetch setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[fetch setFetchLimit: n];
NSArray *results = [MyObject objectWithFetchRequest:fetch];
return results;
```

What I'm wondering is if anybody already knows whether given the fetchLimit `n`:

- the sort is applied to all of the entities in `myObjectList` with matching `objectID` and the first `n` are returned in `results`?
- the first `n` entities with matching `objectID` are fetched from `myObjectList` and then this sub group of `MyObjects` is sorted, most likely resulting in an inaccurate sort?

Basically I'm wondering if I can fetch an ordered set of items without pulling them all out to sort. Looking forward to your responses!

Comment: I would think it is the former and not the latter, but I can't say that I know the facts here. Doing a sort after applying the fetch limit wouldn't be very useful...